# Swift 4 - How do I test for TextView content did change?

Tags: uitextview, ios11, swift4, xcode9

Swift 4, iOS 11 - I have a UITextView that is pre-populated with text but I want users to be able to save any changes they make to the content there. I also have a Save button in the navigation bar and I would like to disable it until the user actually changes the text in the TextView.

I know how to test for empty but I don't know how to test for when the text has been edited. How do I modify the following to test for changes to the content of TextView?

```
@IBAction func textEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextView) {
    updateSaveButtonState()
  }

func updateSaveButtonState() {
    let descriptionText = descriptionTextView.text ?? ""
    saveButton.isEnabled = !descriptionText.isEmpty
  }
```

Comment: using a custom `isEdited` boolean, what becomes `true` inside the `-textViewDidChange(_:)` method and will become `false` after you save the changes?

Comment: holex, your isEdited boolean sounds like it is going in the right direction. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

We'll to use it a dynamic way and not only in single place, i tried to make it easier to implement around the whole app, subclassing the `UITextView` is one of the only ways we got here @holex has suggested `isEdited` boolean flag and it gave me an idea, Thanks to that.

Here is the steps to implement it:

First of all set the defaultText of the textView and set the target of the method that will be called when the textView will be edited, so you can customize what ever you want.

```
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var textView: SBTextView!{
    didSet{
        textView.defaultText = "Hello"
        textView.setTarget = (selector:#selector(self.updateSaveButtonState),target:self)
    }
}
```

Lets say you'll setup the saveButton in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup save button action
    saveButton.action = #selector(saveAction(_:))
    saveButton.target = self
    self.updateSaveButtonState()

}
```

And last is your save action and the selector to update the view using `isEdited` flag.

```
//MARK:- Actions

@objc private func updateSaveButtonState(){

    // has not been changed keep save button disabled
    if self.textView.isEdited == false{
        self.saveButton.isEnabled = false
        self.saveButton.tintColor = .gray
    }else {
        // text has been changed enable save button
        self.saveButton.isEnabled = true
        self.saveButton.tintColor = nil // will reset the color to default
    }
}

@objc private func saveAction(_ saveButton:UIBarButtonItem){

    self.textView.updateDefaultText()

}
```

TextView Custom Class:

```
//
//  SBTextView.swift
//
//
//  Created by Saad Albasha on 11/17/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 AaoIi. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SBTextView: UITextView,UITextViewDelegate {

    var isEdited = false
    private var selector : Selector?
    private var target : UIViewController?
    var setTarget: (selector:Selector?,target:UIViewController?) {
        get{
            return (selector,target)
        }
        set(newVal) {
            selector = newVal.0
            target = newVal.1
        }
    }
    var textViewDefaultText = ""
    var defaultText: String {
        get {
            return textViewDefaultText
        }
        set(newVal) {
            textViewDefaultText = newVal
            self.text = newVal
            self.isEdited = false
        }
    }

    //MARK:- Life Cycle

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)

        self.setupTextview()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.setupTextview()
    }

    private func setupTextview(){

        // setup textview
        self.text = textViewDefaultText
        self.delegate = self

    }

    func updateDefaultText(){

        self.defaultText = self.text!

        // update save button state
        target!.perform(self.selector, with: nil, with: nil)
    }

    //MARK:- Delegate

    internal func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        if textViewDefaultText != textView.text! {
            isEdited = true
        }else {
            isEdited = false
        }

        // update save button state
        target!.perform(self.selector, with: nil, with: nil)
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Aaoli, thank you for the detailed response. At the very beginning of your response it says to keep a reference of the default value. However, the default value for each TextView in the app is multiple paragraphs long and different for each scene. This seems to make it impossible to leverage this option. Isn't there an option to "watch" the TextView for changes regardless of the content?

Comment: @fmz Well, that’s what I understood from your question it wasn’t very clear that you need to use it in multiple places, thus you’ll only have one possible way which is to subclass `UITextView`, Would you like me build such a thing for you ?

Comment: @fmz i have updated my answer, let me know if it works for you